# why Visual studio 2019 missing SQL Service-Based-Database

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2019, sql-data-tools

I am trying to make a Login form in visual studio and I watched few videos and it says that I need to use the SQL server data tool/Service-Based-Database in the solution item section but seems like it's not there. I already checked and it is installed already, anyone knows what I'm doing wrong or what other step should I take?

[image]

[image]

**This is what I am looking for exactly:**
[image]

Comment: What you highlighted isn't part of SSDT. Data tools allow the creation, testing and deployment of database projects, not file types for different types of projects. `Service Based Database` isn't part of SSDT

Comment: Besides, `Service Based Dattabase` is only for *Winforms projects*. The screenshot you posted looks like a `Solution Item` page. Did you click on the wrong node perhaps?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are trying to add a "Solution Item" - you likely right clicked on your *Solution* in solution explorer, rather than one of your projects.  If you right click on your *actual project* in solution explorer and attempt to add an item, you should be able to see the Service-based Database.

So do **one** of the following:

- Right click on your *project* in solution explorer and select Add → New Item.  Then find the Service-based Database item.
- Left click on your project in solution explorer to select it, then in the top menu bar of Visual Studio, click the *Project* menu item, then Add new item and find the Service-based Database.

Comment: Oh my god, thank you so much, and yes that's exactly what I was doing wrong.